# Spark: schema is null

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to figure out how to set schema for Row object.
I am copied code from docs https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql._
 import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

 val innerStruct =
   StructType(
     StructField("f1", IntegerType, true) ::
     StructField("f2", LongType, false) ::
     StructField("f3", BooleanType, false) :: Nil)

 val struct = StructType(
   StructField("a", innerStruct, true) :: Nil)

 // Create a Row with the schema defined by struct
 val row = Row(Row(1, 2, true))
```

However schema is null

```
println(row, row.schema)
// ([[1,2,true]],null)
```

So how to set schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `GenericRowWithSchema` instead of just Row and initialize it with the schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
val row = new GenericRowWithSchema((1, 2, true),schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can create an rdd and then a dataframe with schema specifying from the row as follows:

```
val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.makeRDD(Seq(row))
val dataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd, struct)
println(dataFrame.schema)
```

Will print:

```
StructType(StructField(a,StructType(StructField(f1,IntegerType,true), StructField(f2,LongType,false), StructField(f3,BooleanType,false)),true))
```

Comment: Yes, but i am testing UDF actually. I am passing Seq(Row) to it, so i was thinking that it is possible.

Comment: You cannot test UserDefinedFunction apart from the SparkSession as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

```
  val df=Seq(
             |  (1, 2000l, true),
             |  (3,4500l,false)
             | ).toDF("f1","f2","f3")
        df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [f1: int, f2: bigint ... 1 more field]

         case class TestCase(f1: Int, f2: Long,f3: Boolean)
        defined class TestCase

        val encoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product[TestCase]
        encoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[TestCase] = class[f1[0]: int, f2[0]: bigint, f3[0]: boolean]

         val dataset = df.as(encoder)
        dataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[TestCase] = [f1: int, f2: bigint ... 1 more field]

        dataset.schema
        res6: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(f1,IntegerType,false), StructField(f2,LongType,false), StructField(f3,BooleanType,false))

        df.schema
        res7: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(f1,IntegerType,false), StructField(f2,LongType,false), StructField(f3,BooleanType,false))



         dataset.printSchema
        root
         |-- f1: integer (nullable = false)
         |-- f2: long (nullable = false)
         |-- f3: boolean (nullable = false)
```